# Why is Angular losing the "£" signs from my templates?

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm working in Angular and mostly it seems to be fine but I'm having a problem because I live in the kind of country that uses `£` as our currency and when my source code looks like this:

```html
<span class="spend"> £ {{lineItem.cost}} </span>
```

My output looks like this:

> � 120.00

My source files are all in a standard UTF-8 encoding and have no problem with the symbol, if I open the template straight in the browser it looks right, so it seems as though somewhere in the `ng build` process it is losing the character. My google-fu is failing me on this one because when I talk about characters getting filtered out I just get results for Angular filters, and apparently people only know the '#' sign as the pound.

What do I have to do to retain the pound sign in my Angular templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `&pound;` instead of `£` in HTML ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp))

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the currency pipe to display the pound symbol `£` in your template?

```html
<span class="spend">{{lineItem.cost | currency: 'GBP'}}</span>
```

In case you don't want any decimal places

```html
<span class="spend">{{lineItem.cost | currency: 'GBP': 'symbol': '1.0-0'}}</span>
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but also seems like a lot more work for a static character in a scenario where it is not expected to ever need to change.